# Work a medium of energy conversion?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, work

Is work a medium to convert one form of energy to other? i.e. to say without work you can't convert type of energy?

Similar type of question pertains to heat.heat is also medium of conversion of energy?

can we say that if there is no heat change and work done then energy cant be converted from one form to other?

I am asking it from the perspective of First law of thermodynamics as it often confuses
Please guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/195446/)

Comment: i think we are dealing with physics, and for basic understanding it better to avoid math for interpretations

Comment: You either have a limited view of physics, a limited view of mathematics, or both. Even if you don't like equations, the very act of studying physics requires mathematical thinking in terms of understanding definitions, theorems relating and characterizing these definitions, and conditions under which these theorem's apply. To study physics is ultimately to study mathematics as well.